# How do you pass variables to SASS using MVC3 / C# / Razor?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc-3, sass, less

In my current MVC3 project we are implementing a theming function where user can choose a palette of colours that will be used throughout the site.

To do this I need to be able to pass their choices to my style sheets. It seems my choices are dotless or SASS, I prefer the look of SASS but cannot work out how to pass arguments to it.

With dotless you can pass arguments to it in the querystring when you reference the style sheet, below I am passing the hex codes for the chosen blue and green colours:

```
<link href="/Content/Site.less?blue=%23134988&amp;green=%23008000&amp;"
      rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

These variables are then accessible within the style sheet using `@blue` or `@green`.

Can anyone tell me how to achieve the same thing using SASS?

Comment: As far as I know no such sass parser/compiler exists for .net yet; we checked a couple around here, but couldn't find anything outstanding for sass; nowdays less seems to be more popular for dotnet projects, which is a shame, since sass debug info can be very helpful in my opinion.

Comment: thats a shame, but at least it confirms that i wasn't just missing it, thank you